# Lua copy and split table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have one large table that contains a large number of recursive sub-tables:

```
table1={p1={def={...}},
        p2={...},
        p3={...},
        ...
        p(n)={...}
}
```

I need to get a copy of this table that contains only certain sub-tables

```
plist={"p1", "p3", "p10",...}
```

As a result, I should get a table of the form:

```
table2={p1={def={...}},
        p3={...},
        p10={...},
        ...
}
```

table1 should remain unchanged.

I tryed using this code:

```
function deepcopy(o, seen)
  seen = seen or {}
  if o == nil then return nil end
  if seen[o] then return seen[o] end
  local no
  if type(o) == 'table' then
    no = {}
    seen[o] = no
    for k, v in next, o, nil do
      no[deepcopy(k, seen)] = deepcopy(v, seen)
    end
    setmetatable(no, deepcopy(getmetatable(o), seen))
  else
    no = o
  end
  return o
end

local table2 = deepcopy(plist, table1)
```

And this:

```
local function copy(obj, seen)
  if type(obj) ~= 'table' then return obj end
  if seen and seen[obj] then return seen[obj] end
  local s = seen or {}
  local res = setmetatable({}, getmetatable(obj))
  s[obj] = res
  for k, v in pairs(obj) do res[copy(k, s)] = copy(v, s) end
  return res
end
local table2 = copy(plist, table1)
```

Both give me not right table2. What code should i use?

Comment: `local table2 = {}; for _,k in ipairs(plist) do table2[k] = table1[k] end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best stratagy here is to first filter and then perform a deep copy, because it's hard to correctly filter only the top level while still performing a deep copy.

```lua
function filter(tb, fields)
    local ret = {}
    for i, field in ipairs(fields) do
        ret[field] = tb[field]
    end
    return ret
end

-- Taken from luno library: https://github.com/echiesse/luno/blob/master/src/util.lua
function copy(val, lookup)
    local ret
    lookup = lookup or {}
    if type(val) == "table" then
        if lookup[val] ~= nil then
            ret = lookup[val]
        else
            ret = {}
            lookup[val] = ret
            for i, v in pairs(val) do
                local index = lookup[i] or copy(i, lookup)
                local value = lookup[v] or copy(v, lookup)
                ret[index] = value
            end
        end
    else
        ret = val
    end
    return ret
end


function filterAndCopy(tb, fields, lookup)
    local temp = filter(tb, fields)
    return copy(temp)
end
```

And you can test this way:

```lua
a = {a=1, b=2}
b = filterAndCopy(a, {"b"})
for k, v in pairs(b) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Which yields the output:

```
b       2
```

Comment: Just saw that I'm not dealing with metatables during the copy. I think it's just a matter of replacing the line `ret = {}` by `ret = setmetatable({}, getmetatable(val))`